# In operator alternative in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Select col1,col2,col3 from table1 where col4 in (1,2,3,4);
```

Is there any other way to do instead of 'in' in mysql select query?

If i use in operator, there is some performance limit, appreciate if you have other suggestions.

Comment: "If i use in operator, there is some performance limit, appreciate if you have other suggestions." --- uhm, what!? Can you describe the **origins** of the question, not your personal (wrong) thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using IN operator should NOT have performance issues.

If you insist NOT using `IN` operator, replace your query with:

```
Select col1,col2,col3 from table1 where col4=1 OR col4=2 OR col4=3 OR col4=4;
```