# Alternative to in operator in mysql

Tags: mysql, in-operator

I see [In operator alternative in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045211/in-operator-alternative-in-mysql)

I have nearly `25,000` ids.I am using `in` operator on that.Then i am getting `Stackoverflow Exception`.Is there any other alternative for IN operator in mysql.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can use `exist`.. It is faster than `In` . Exist will stop searching when it has found 1 match http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999600/mysql-difference-between-in-and-exist

Comment: you can dynamically generate query and replace IN with OR statements in loop. but result will be the same(or worse) I guess... maybe slicing the query to few smallest queries is the option(5 queries with 5000 elements)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ID's are in another table:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2);
```

then you can use a join instead:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

**1 - Create a [MySQL Temporary Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempIdTable (id int unsigned not null primary key);
```

**2 - Insert All Your ids into the Temporary Table**

For every id in your list:

```
insert ignore into myId (id) values (anId);
```

(this will have the added bonus of de-duplicating your list of ids ready for the final step)

**3 - Join Against the Temporary Table**

```
SELECT t1.* FROM myTable1 t1 INNER JOIN tempIdTable tt ON t1.id = tt.id;
```

The temporary table will disappear as soon as your connection is dropped so your don't have to worry about dropping it before you create it next time.