# MySQL IN Operator Alternative

Tags: mysql

In my query I have to find all the records with the comma separated id's below.

```
2,20,44,66,68,85,90,101,102,103,125,168
```

So I wrote the below query for the task

```
SELECT item_id, 
       item_name 
FROM   `items` 
WHERE  `item_id` IN ( 2, 20, 44, 66, 
                      68, 85, 90, 101, 
                      102, 103, 125, 168 )
```

But the problem is that when the comma separated ID list is large query execution time will become large. Is there any other way to accomplish my task.

My Table structure after DESCRIBE table query is below. Please check

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra   
asheet_id   int(11) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
asheet_staff_id int(11) unsigned    NO      NULL    
asheet_exam_number  int(11) NO      NULL
```

Comment: Correct indexes would (most probably) solve the problem

Comment: item_id is primary key? - if not so: ALTER TABLE `items` ADD INDEX item_id_index (`item_id`)

Comment: I do not there is a better way of doing. Create an index on the item_id to improve perfomance

Comment: yes item_id is the primary key

Comment: @Alchemist can You execute? `DESCRIBE items;`

Comment: I can't speak for MySQL but in Oracle I found that it generates the same exact execution plan that good old `item_id=2 OR item_id=20 OR...` and it performs nicely for huge lists. You should do the same verification.

Comment: If the list is truly huge, consider storing it in a separate (indexed) table.

Comment: Try out the last answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562901/alternative-to-in-operator-in-mysql You already generated or have a hold of the ids you are looking for so creating a temp table wouldn't be a big deal... I've not tried it but it is an alternative.

Comment: @Alchemist have You fixed Your issue?

Comment: Nope. indexing have no effect in the speed.

Comment: @Alchemist try `UNION ALL SELECT` technique

Comment: @num8er How to perform UNION ALL SELECT if the comma separated list is huge like 500 values.

Comment: oh :D You've not defined in question. so better tune up Your mysql settings

Comment: @Alchemist have You changed items table engine to MyISAM ? Also add some pagination (50 items per page) using `LIMIT 0, 50`. cuz getting huge response is also makes a cost on performance.

Comment: @num8er Changing to MyISAM have no effect on the speed. Limiting the records also limit the records returned but the speed is still the same. I have edited my question for including table structure.

Comment: @Alchemist You're doing SELECT ... IN on `asheet_id` ?

Comment: @num8er yes. for understanding easily I named it as item :)

Comment: @Alchemist Yes, it's ok. I got it (:

Comment: @Alchemist what about the load of Your app, how many active users and etc You've? I'm asking it because I think that if after all the stuff was in answers of all users it's still same slow so maybe it's time to change algorhythms or use ElasticSearch to index it to not make a load on DB?

Comment: @num8er I have no idea what you have just said. Let me chk it and will get back to you soon. Now I am not running this query from the app, I am running it on MySQL. So I think including this query in my application will be a heavy load....

Answer (score 0):

`item_id` is primary key?

execute:

```
DESCRIBE items;
```

and put result to question

1) if `YES` so investigate You server's memory, query cache, query concurrency, network/socket connection and etc factors. maybe slow part is not with Your query, but in another part of Your app? so please describe in question/comments how You check it. 
take a look at `my.cnf` there are many params that can help You tune up mysql performance.

2) if `NO` so add index: `ALTER TABLE items ADD INDEX item_id_index (item_id)`

**IF**: Your `items` table does not get to often `UPDATE` queries to it's better to change engine to `MyISAM`, it's fast for `SELECT` queries

Also I'd say let's try following techniques:

1) `UNION SELECT` with each id, cuz if it's PK it will work as `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT item_id, item_name FROM  items WHERE item_id = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT item_id, item_name FROM  items WHERE item_id = 20
UNION ALL
.
.
UNION ALL
SELECT item_id, item_name FROM  items WHERE item_id = 168
```

2) Create a view and send Your query to it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_items AS 
SELECT item_id, item_name FROM items;

SELECT * FROM vw_items WHERE item_id IN (...);
```

also in case of Your db has many requests and if `items` table is does have update queries try to cache queries to db using `memcache`, `redis`

p.s. doing `JOIN` or `sub query` operation will not gain performance because in both of cases it will use same index on `item_id` field.

Comment: First you have to analyse how is your data related to the array  ( 2,20,44,66,68,85,90,101,102,103,125,168 ). If you can store array values in database and make some to logic with item table; you can use join operation.

Comment: @bikramkc don't make me laugh. FIRST: if it's PK it will work at max effectiveness and find what's needed. SECOND: doing JOIN operation will not gain performance because even in JOIN it will use same index that is defined on `item_id` field.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create a `Temporary Table`, Fill that table with those data and then perform a `JOIN` like

```
create temporary table test(Id int);

insert into test
select 2
union
select 99 from dual;
```

Then perform a join with that table

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name 
FROM  `items` i
JOIN test t ON i.item_id = t.Id;
```

This approach would be better than having a huge `IN` list since that in list will internally get flatten to chained `OR` condition and moreover, every RDBMS have limit on number of element in `IN` (not sure about `MySQL` but say `NETEZZA` have a restriction of 5000 element or so).

Instead performing a `JOIN` would generate a much efficient execution plan. If `SQL Server` then you can as well choose to use a `Table Type Variable`

Comment: do I have to include all the records from my table to the temporary table. If it is like that then the inner join will also return all the records from item table.